# Как найти в таблице в файле docx множество словосочетаний (регулярных выражений) с помощью python?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-docx

Требуется найти, есть ли совпадения нескольких словосочетаний (регулярных выражений) в таблице в файле docx, и вывести все совпадения на экран.

Вот какой код я пишу:

```
import re

from docx import Document

document = Document('Altai.docx')
reg542 = [re.compile("(?i).....name one.*"),
               re.compile("(?i).....name two.*")]


for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                if re.match(reg542, paragraph.text):
                    print (paragraph.text)
```

Пишет, что ошибка

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
reg542 = re.compile("(?i).....name one.*|(?i).....name two.*")
```

Если таких выражений будет много, то можно их через `'|'.join()` соединить из списка, если так будет удобнее.

Comment: Ругается на соединенный список через |

_SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd0' in file /Users/pal/PycharmProjects/Finding words/main.py on line 46, but no encoding declared_

Answer (score 0):

This one worked

```
import re

from docx import Document

document = Document('file.docx')

reg542 = re.compile(r"(?i)regex 1.*"
                    r"|(?i)regex 2.*"
                    r"|(?i)regex n.*")

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                if reg542.search(paragraph.text):
                    print(paragraph.text)
```